# How to count classified points in polygons?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

is there a way to merge the attribute table of a csv file into a the attribute table of a vector? Join is not the answer for me because in this way the plugin GroupStats that you suggested me to use for counting the elements in the table doesn't work properly; in fact I need to count accommodations for every municipality in my province and using Join feature between municipality vector and accommodation file doesn't count the number of the elements that I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't test it it, but I think the [MMQGIS](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) plugin can merge a CSV and a vector layer (go to the *Attribute Join from CSV File* section):

[image]

It should output a vector layer with the attributes of the original layer and the CSV file, joined according to a field.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Count Points in Polygon` process from the `Vector`->`Analysis` -> `Points in Polygon` menu.

[image]

You simply put your municipality layer in as the polygon layer, and the accommodation as the point layer. Select an output shapefile and then run it.

Finally you can merge the file back into your municipalities if you need to.

Comment: Thank you, but in this way I get a column with the sum of the accommodations in each municipality, I need to know how many hotels, B&Bs, hostels, etc.. there are in each of them.. Is this possible?

Comment: Try selecting the category you want before you do the join

Comment: sorry, in which menu?

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat circuitous, but you may have luck saving a copy of the vector file after you Join the CSV to it. That way, the exported file should contain all of the CSV attributes without it being connected through a Join. Perhaps that would help address the issues you're encountering when using the plugin.